# Keycloak Authentication invalid_client_credentials

Tags: reactjs, keycloak

I am trying to implement a basic Keycloak authentication on my react website.
During the authentication init, authentication is failing and on the react server side I am getting the error invalid_client_credentials.

Once I goto my react website I am prompted with a Keycloak login page, where I enter username and password and I login successfully. But does not execute any part of the code after init.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Keycloak from 'keycloak-js';

const keycloak = Keycloak({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/',
    realm: 'reactrealm',
    clientId: 'reactclient',
    clientSecret: 'xvtYZ5P7ybsjvmAO4YY2Eu6NifsePLBg'
});

keycloak.init({ onLoad: 'login-required' }).then((authenticated) => {
    if (authenticated) {
        ReactDOM.render(
                <h1>Hello, world!</h1>,
            document.getElementById('root')
        );
    } else {
        ReactDOM.render(
                <h1>Goodbye, world!</h1>,
            document.getElementById('root')
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Please provide Keycloak's client configuration.

Answer (score 1):

Generally we get this error in new keycloak UI when we enable "client authentication" in "capability config" of client. Please make sure it is disabled and standard flow and direct grant are only ticked.
Following steps may help you for keycloak latest UI :

1. Creation new realm
2. Setting home url, base url, redirect url, web origins
3. Setting "authentication flow overrides" in advanced tab of client, "Browser Flow" to browser and "Direct Grant Flow" to "direct grant"
4. Create User and Role, assign Role to User and make sure role should contain client scope and client scope should include web origin so that you will not face issue with CORS and tokens
   and then you can check

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, plus authentication flow overrides do not seem relevant here, so is enabling DIrect Grant (which is also discouraged nowadays, unless specifically needed for a certain use case). Besides the question requires clarification.